# Choose printer when printing from JS

Tags: javascript, pdf, printing, rendering

I'm trying to write some code to print my page. However, I'd like to choose printer myself (e.g. virtual PDF) to make sure user has it by default when print dialogue pops up.

Is it even achievable in JS? I read multiple articles about `print()` function but I didn't find anything like printer selection.

Unfortunately, I don't have any code to provide since I don't know it it's even possible. In a nutshell, the question is if it's possible to choose some value from this dropdown programatically

[image]

Something like

```js
function printPdf() {
   print({printer: "pdf"});
}
```

where `print()` is [default printing function](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_print.asp).

Comment: _I'd like to choose printer myself (e.g. virtual PDF) to make sure user has it by default.._ In other words you're looking for a way to install 3rd-party software on an user' machine via JS?

Comment: No, I want to programmically choose a printer. See code snipped in the edit.

Comment: Just curious, what if a user doesn't have the printer you needed?

Comment: Then it may be the first one. It's just about setting default, if appropriate.

Comment: I'm afraid you just can't. JS has no access to printer options. However, there is an [alternative](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/printerProvider) which may be interesting for you.

Comment: Cool. Gonna try that.